# (iPhone iOS 4) App that was closed and removed from background bar

Tags: iphone, ios4

Consider an app that was in the multitask bar, and was closed, clicking on the minus sign.

What is supposed to be the behavior of this app at restart?

Does the app restart from scratch with the splash screen and without old data?

Or does the app load saved data and restart without splash screen and with previous data reloaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application should restore its previous state in as many cases as possible. Prior to multitasking, all the applications tried to do this, to give the users the impression of multitasking. With multitasking in iOS 4, this doesn't change. You still need to do this to:

- Support older devices.
- Keep the user experience the same even if the user opens tons of apps and the device frees memory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If its closed then it will start from "scratch" unless you use the app delegate methods which are fired to store data and create the functionality to reload somewhere specific in your app yourself.

The splash screen will show if there is loading time needed, just like when you start an app the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think a user who clicks the minus is probably doing it, either just to clean up, or because he/she would like the app to return to it's beginning setup, just as if the device was reset.

I handle the minus, just like that, and start fresh with the splash screen. (not sure what the apple guide recommends)

Answer (score 0):

This operation (tapping on minus icon) is intended for freeing memory.
When Apple has introduced multitasking in iOS, usage of memory has increased a lot!

So, why you have to tap on minus to kill application? When do you have to do this?
When your device responsiveness is too bad.

After killing (closing) application, when you restart the app, it start from scratch or resume last operation depending on how the application has developed!

For example, look at FacebookApp. If you are logged-in and quit app, at next restart it's reopen your account and last page seen!

Answer (score 0):

For something like a game, I would suggest you restore the user's state ONLY IF they were in the middle of a game, else just start from scratch. However, for anything else, always start from scratch.

If you do nothing, your app will probably start from scratch at the moment.